# Is the `gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments` safe to ignore?

Tags: c++, c++11, warnings, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

Consider the following code [**(live example)**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7924734a01cc9956):

```
#define TEST_VA(mX, ...) TEST
#define STRINGIFY_IMPL(mX) #mX
#define STRINGIFY(mX) STRINGIFY_IMPL(mX)

#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << STRINGIFY(TEST_VA(1)) << std::endl;
    std::cout << STRINGIFY(TEST_VA()) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

---

**clang++ 3.4** complains:

```
main.cpp:9:37: warning: must specify at least one argument for '...' parameter of variadic macro [-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments]
    std::cout << STRINGIFY(TEST_VA(1)) << std::endl;
                                    ^
main.cpp:1:9: note: macro 'TEST_VA' defined here
#define TEST_VA(mX, ...) TEST
        ^
main.cpp:10:33: warning: must specify at least one argument for '...' parameter of variadic macro [-Wgnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments]
        std::cout << STRINGIFY(TEST_VA()) << std::endl;
                                       ^
main.cpp:1:9: note: macro 'TEST_VA' defined here
#define TEST_VA(mX, ...) TEST
```

---

I use some variadic macros like in the example code in my projects.

Is it safe to pass no arguments for the `...` parameter of variadic macros? (Ignoring the warning, basically)

Or could it lead to problems?

Is it explicitly forbidden by the standard?

Comment: @FrançoisMoisan The [working standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) contains sections relative to macros and preprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's technically forbidden by the standard.  From C++11 §16.3/4 (emphasis added):

> If the identifier-list in the macro definition does not end with an ellipsis, the number of arguments (including
>   those arguments consisting of no preprocessing tokens) in an invocation of a function-like macro shall equal
>   the number of parameters in the macro definition. **Otherwise, there shall be more arguments in the invocation than there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`)**.  There shall exist a `)` preprocessing
>   token that terminates the invocation.

Some compilers may allow this as an extension, but if you want standards-compliant code, you should make sure to always include at least one argument for the ellipsis parameter of a variadic macro.

Comment: I'm relying on zero-arguments variadic macros for compile time preprocessor recursion (foreach, tuples). Is there a workaround?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: That obviously depends on what exactly you're trying to do.  I personally wouldn't recommend trying to do such complicated things with the C preprocessor; if you really need to do that, you could try using a different, more flexible preprocessor instead, such as GNU m4 or a custom script.  Using tools like that wouldn't be too hard to integrate into a Makefile-based build system, but it would make your build system more brittle and difficult to work with.

Comment: A basic example is countin variadic arguments. Seems like [boost has my same issue](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/preprocessor/variadic/size.hpp)

Answer (score 4):

Starting from C++20, passing zero arguments to a variadic macro parameter is allowed, but Clang (at least Clang 12) doesn't respect this change yet.

So if you're targeting C++20 or newer and using `-pedantic-errors`, then `-Wno-gnu-zero-variadic-macro-arguments` is recommended.

---

> #### [`[cpp.replace.general]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.replace.general#5)
>
> ... there shall be at least as many arguments in the invocation as there are parameters in the macro definition (excluding the `...`).